# Why do my desktop icons get re-organized when I Remote Desktop in?

Tags: remote-desktop, desktop, icons

Whenever I remote into my work computer from home or vice-versus the shortcuts, folders and files get reorganized which is extremely frustrating since I often group things into clusters on my desktop.

While the resolution of the two systems are different, I always make sure to keep everything on the higher resolution system within the confines of the resolution for the smaller.

Does anyone else have this problem and find it annoying?  Does anyone have a solution or suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Work around; use application/plugin to restore the layout.

I am a big fan of [Desktop Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/), which creates labelled groups of icons with persistent positions.

There's also ["Remember Desktop Icon layout"](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/save-and-restore-desktop-icon-layout-in-windows-vista/) reg addon to WinXP+.

Comment: Just installed Desktop Fences...pretty great, though I wished they snapped to one another when you moved them close.  The double click feature is a really nice touch.

Comment: @BlueNovember, thanks for the work-around.  Not sure I want to go to the extreme of installing an application like that to solve the problem.  Any ideas as to why it happens in the first place?

Comment: Icons are re-arranged if they go outside the viewable desktop size. I would assume that RD does something stupid like create a 0-sized desktop then expand it to the desired client size. Whatever the cause, the problem sure is irritating, and I doubt there's a patch to fix it. =(