# RDP connections changes target desktop icon positions

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

When connecting to my remote Windows 7 desktop with RDP, once I disconnect and later go back to this computer, all the desktop icons are rearranged from the way they had been, necessitating me to place them back in a certain order.
Does anyone know a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Sounds like could be different screen resolution settings in the Remote Desktop sessions

Comment: See  [Desktop icons rearrange after using remote desktop connection](http://superuser.com/questions/160421/desktop-icons-rearrange-after-using-remote-desktop-connection), and http://superuser.com/questions/290078/how-do-i-stop-windows-from-moving-desktop-icons AND http://superuser.com/questions/100416/why-do-my-desktop-icons-get-re-organized-when-i-remote-desktop-in AND http://superuser.com/questions/933228/remote-desktop-rearranges-icons-but-not-so-they-would-fit-better-in-small-resol AND http://superuser.com/questions/386409/realign-remote-desktop-session-icons-to-physical-desktops

Comment: oh and http://superuser.com/questions/944271/rdp-connections-changes-target-desktop-icon-positions... Did you do any research first? Either way, hopefully one of these helps

Answer (score 1):

This is a side effect of changing the resolution. It is worse when you switch to a lower resolution than the native desktop resolution though. The fix is to simply use the same resolution that the remote desktop uses in your remote desktop session. This is done by choosing it on the Display tab of Remote Desktop:

[image]

Comment: Correct. This is a side effect of explorer + DWM having to resize to meet the new resolution.